# P value calculation for stacked LSTM model for binary classification

Tags: classification, time-series, pvalue

I need to calculate the P-value for a stacked LSTM model. Does that mean that I need to run the model multiple times and consider the null hypothesis that the model's accuracy is almost the same across the multiple runs? if not can you please help me with how to do it correctly?

Comment: p-value of what?

Comment: P-value for the model's results. Like accuracy and so on